# linux ssh agent and add : avoid repeating command

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, capifony

When I'm deploying my application from my server using capifony, I need to start by typping those commands for the authentication to work :

```
$(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

If I disconnect, I have to retype this otherwise I get the following error :

```
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
 ** [xx :: err] Error writing to authentication socket.
 ** [xx :: err] Permission denied (publickey).
 ** [xx :: err] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I'mnot an expert, what does the ssh-agent and ssh-add ?
How to avoid repeating this all the time ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Enable ForwardAgent in your ssh configuration.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
ForwardAgent yes
```

Then open a new shell to have you agent up and running.

Comment: hi! can you elaborate on this ? I had no config file so I created it and added ForwardAgent yes. does not seem to be the right move

Comment: Did you started a new shell afterward? are you on linux or something like sygwin?

Comment: here on linux. did I do the right thing in putting this in a new config file?

Comment: yes creating the file is ok! do you know on which remote server your script connects to? if yes can you dump the result of ssh -vvv <SERVER> on pastebin or equivalent.

Comment: An other possible cause might be that your ssh key is not in a std location or name. ssh -vvv will tell us.

Comment: ok, it worked adding my two lines to ~/.profile file
if you edit your answer I can accept it

Comment: what 2 lines? what is your linux distro?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the following resolved my issue with Linux Ubuntu 15.04.

i added the follwoing two lines at the end of ~/.profile

So it becomes :

```
sudo nano ~/.profile

#go at the end and writeout

$(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```